# Google tag manager Parse error. ',' expected

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to save this Custom Javascript Variable within Google Tag Manager and return this error each time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
sendinblue.identify('$_POST['_username']',{
  'PRENOM': '$_POST['customer_checkout[data][firstname]']',
  'NOM' : '$_POST['customer_checkout[data][lastname]']'
});
</script>
```

Google tag manager tell me : Parse error. ',' expected.

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you for your help

Joris

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your snippet contains PHP code `$_POST['_username']`, `$_POST['customer_checkout[data][firstname]']`,`$_POST['customer_checkout[data][lastname]']`. Your custom Javascript variable should contain only JS without any server-side languages

UPDATE

One of the ways of passing data to GTM:

If you have this values stored on the website, then **on your website** you should create hidden inputs:

```
<input value="$_POST['_username']" id="hiddenUsername"/>
<input value="$_POST['customer_checkout[data][firstname]']" id="hiddenFirstname"/>
<input value="$_POST['customer_checkout[data][lastname]']" id="hiddenLastname"/>
```

And then **in GTM** you can read data from this inputs:

```
 sendinblue.identify(document.getElementById('hiddenUsername').value,{
    'PRENOM': document.getElementById('hiddenFirstname').value,
     'NOM' : document.getElementById('hiddenLasttname').value
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

I need to put a code in Google Tag Manager to track my visitor with Sendinblue (mailing tool).

So, I find these variables in my website form $_POST['_username'], $_POST['customer_checkout[data][firstname]'],$_POST['customer_checkout[data][lastname]'].

Following your answer, I need to change my variables or other think in my code ?

Thank you